# How to convert javascript regex to safe java regex?

Tags: java, javascript, regex

```
strOutput.replace("/{{[^]*?}}/g","");
```

Is there a way to convert JavaScript regexes to Java-safe regexes?

The above statement gives me the error:

> `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

I'm not all that familiar with regex, so I could use some guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the Java you've created that gave you the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get rid of the forward slashes. You don't need those in Java. Also, Java's flavor of regex doesn't recognize switches like `/g` and `/i`; those are controlled by constants in `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

The only Javascript regex switches that make sense in the Java world are `/i` and `/m`. These map to `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `Pattern.MULTILINE` (you can use these switches when creating a regex from the `Pattern` class, or you can use them inline -- I'll show this later).

The `/g` doesn't map to anything, but you can control replace behavior by using [`String.replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) versus [`String.replaceFirst`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

To get your code to work, you'd have to do something like this:

```
strOutput.replaceAll("{{[^]*?}}", "");
```

If you wanted to use switches, you need to do add something like `(?i)` to the beginning of the regex.

You can't use [`String.replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) because it takes in a `CharSequence` for the first argument and not a regex.

Also keep in mind that the "quick regex" methods offered by the `String` class may not work like you expect it to. This is because when you specify a pattern (let's say `abc`) as a regex for `matches` for example, the actual pattern seen by Java is `^abc$`. So `abc` will match, but `abcd` will not.

There is more information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `"/"` and `"/g"` at the start and the end of regex. Then you need to escape every `"\"` occurrence like so: `"\\"`.

The "g" part means global. This is controlled in how you use regex in Java as opposed to in the regex string.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need the `/`'s (forward slashes at start and end) those are used in javascript for inline declaration instead of quotes.

Should just be `Regex r = new Regex("{{[^]*?}}");`
​​​​