# JavaScript Regular Expression to Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a small piece of relic code written in Javascript that scans a web page source and looks for the pattern.

I am migrating the functuanality to a Java program. So, my questiong is how can I parse a JavaScript regular expression to a java one with some kind of find and replace function?

For example my JavaScript Regex currently reads (as a String)

`RegEx = "/(\\/addthis_widget\\.(js|php)|\\.addthis\\.com\\/js\\/widget\\.(js|php))/i";`

I found this old post on stackoverflow:

[How to convert javascript regex to safe java regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788413/how-to-convert-javascript-regex-to-safe-java-regex)

which sudgests that this would do the trick:

`strOutput.replace("/{{[^]*?}}/g","");`

However, this does not seem robust enough and does not produce a RegEx which is recognised by the compiler.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to automatically generate a Java regular expression from a JavaScript regular expression. I'm not sure if there are any tools for this, though.

Comment: This question also discusses conversion of regular expressions from JavaScript to Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754444/convert-javascript-regular-expression-to-java-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Remove the / at the start and /i at the end.
Add (?i) at the start.

Java doesn't use `/expr/options` format. `/expr/G` would be replaced by \G boundary match, but in java you generally just call `matcher.find()` multiple times, and it will start searching for the match at the end of previous one automatically, making \G pointless.

Change all `\\/` to `/`, forwards slashes don't need to be escaped.