# How to set PrimeFaces KeyFilter to discard 0(Zero) as the first digit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have a PrimeFaces InputText. I Need to make it accept only numbers, that are greater than zero.

I have tried this approach.

```html
<p:inputText id="levelId"
    value="#{myBean.levelValue}" converter="spaceConverter">
    <pe:keyFilter  for="levelId" regEx="/^[1-9][0-9]*$/i" />
</p:inputText>
```

But this won't allow the input of 0 at all. That is, by the above approach I cant enter 10.

---

I tried the following approach as well:

```html
<pe:inputNumber decimalPlaces="0" id="levelId"
        value="#{myBean.levelValue}"minValue=1 maxValue="10">                   
</pe:inputNumber>
```

PS: default value of levelValue is 1

In this approach it won't allow me to remove the default value and enter other value(ex:4) because minValue is set to 1

---

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using regex with p:keyFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083226/using-regex-with-pkeyfilter)

Comment: You are probably using an older version of PrimeFaces. Note that `pe:keyFilter` has been migrated to `p:keyFilter`.

Comment: Yeah, I have been using older version of Primefaces, which doesn't have keyFilter

Comment: Same answer applies

Comment: But validateRegEx will allow me to input 0 as the first character and then regex fails. My requirement is user should not be able to input 0 as first character at all

Comment: Remove the JavaScript syntax (`/.../`) from your regex. You can test your expression in a `main` method of a Java class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754444/convert-javascript-regular-expression-to-java-syntax/52925590

Comment: Also use `<p:inputNumber minValue="0"`

Comment: If there is an issue with `pe:inputNumber`, upgrade and try with `p:inputNumber`.

Comment: @Melloware I tried that. But that wont let me backspace(remove) the default number 1 inorder to enter any other number(say 5). So by adding minValue=1, only way to enter 5 is by entering 15 first and then removing 1.

Comment: I think you are using an old PrimeFaces?  I think that has been fixed a long time ago with `minValue=0` ??

Comment: @Melloware. Yeah, may be that's the case. I will check. Thanks!