# Javascript to Java Regex

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this regex. When using a regex test and such I get the result that I want however, I am unable to produce the same thing in Java

```
/^(?: {4})+(?=.+)/gm
```

Comment: We're gonna need a little bit more than that... What's your input? What are the two ouputs? What do you want to do? Please edit the question to answer and give some examples.

Comment: Apart from all those this regex looks suspicious too

Comment: get rid of `/` and `/gm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Pattern.MULTILINE` for the `/m` modifier(or flag). And use the iterator for the `/g`. And of course remove the delimiters `/` from the both end of your regex. Please see this example:

```
String input = "...some input...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?: {4})+(?=.+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

// Using iterator doing the /g part here
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `/gm` form the regex. This is javascript regex not java.
If you want to convert javascript regex to java, we already have an answer here. See [How to convert javascript regex to safe java regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788413/how-to-convert-javascript-regex-to-safe-java-regex)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?: {4})+(?=.+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```