# Convert JavaScript regular expression to java

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am trying to convert JavaScript regular expression to java regular expression. here is my current javascript regular expression that I am trying to convert :

```
var re = /\a(?![^<]*>)/g;
```

I have searched and found out that I need to change the back-slash / into double back-slashes // and start with " 
but what about /g  at the end? do we need to change it too?
Thank you

Comment: could you please why the down vote? please advice. thank you

Comment: not sure, /g is not recognized http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788413/how-to-convert-javascript-regex-to-safe-java-regex maybe also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628715/java-regex-to-get-the-text-from-html-anchor-a-a-tags

Comment: The downvote is probably because your question is poorly written and poorly researched.  (And it probably means that people think your question wouldn't be useful for others in the future.  Not least because the writing is unclear ... and (based on the comments on the answer) the regex is not correct in Javascript either.

Comment: @StephenC the regex  is correct in Javascript  it is working fine. Also I edited my question to make it more clear. Thank you for your comment

Comment: So what does the "\a" mean in the Javascript version??  They have pretty much concluded that it is nonsense in the Java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent regex is:

```
string regex = "\\a(?![^<]*>)";
```

There is no equivalent of the `g` flag in JAVA, you have to use [`replaceall()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) instead of `replace()` if you want to replace or use a matcher and a while loop (see [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884484/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-android)).

Comment: What is the purpose of escaping the letter `a` in a regex? In JS, `/\a/.exec("\\a")[0]` => `"a"`. Java regex engine does not treat `\a` in any special way either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew absolutely no use, except to show OP that a backslash should be escaped in a string

Comment: I used that but it is not working ..... it should detect any letter a outside <a /> tags

Comment: @MuadhProgrammer could you provide input

Comment: Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\a(?![^<]*>)").matcher("ahddsa a jfkfa a jf a" );
        while (m.find()) {
            Log.i("Found:  ",  m.group(0));
        }

Comment: @MuadhProgrammer in Java, the `\a` is interpreted as the ASCII 7 char, remove the backslashes and it should work. See [demo](https://ideone.com/MWe5Nd)